# How to Create a Git metadata(.git folder)?

Tags: git, github

How to Create a Git metadata(.git folder) in the tarball so that I can look at my commit logs and understand how the solution evolved.

Comment: `man git-bundle`

Comment: After doing cd .git/ I can access the info of my repo. But the folder is not visible. Where can i find it. I want to include that folder with other files of the project.

Comment: `ls -al` to see your `.git` folder

Comment: Hi, @ParthShah I was given a task to use ​Git​ for version control for my project. And I need to send a zip or tarball of my source code that includes the Git metadata(.git folder) in the tarball so that the other team can  look at my commit logs and understand how my solution evolved. I have basic understanding of git. Can you share some knowledge how can I do it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: During the development of your solution, have you used git? Is there a `.git` folder in your source code directory?

Comment: Yes, I have used git during the development and initialised it using git init and done all the commits necessary. Also while doing cd .git/ I can see the contents in the folder.

Comment: Just `tar -czf filename.tgz` your project folder, it will contain your current source + git history. If you really want to send just the .git folder without the current source : `tar -czf filename.tgz project/.git`

Comment: It is more usual to post the project to github. But a git folder is a folder like any other; if you zip the project folder, the zip will contain the git folder. It's invisible but it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Simply compressing upper directory, that is directory containing your `.git`, will work. Such *tgz* file should contain all files including hidden ones.

```
ls -a
. .. some-source-file.cpp .git
cd ..
tar czf project.tgz project
```

Unpacking by

```
tar xzf project.tgz
```

Will provide the other team with both source code and `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also recursively zip the contents of your source code folder. The `.git` folder will be added.

```
$ ls
SourceCode    Documents    ...
$ zip -r SourceCode.zip SourceCode/
```

You will now have a zip folder called `SourceCode.zip`. This will contain all the original contents including the git history, compressed. If you get an error that says `command not found: zip`, you can install zip using the command `sudo apt install zip` in your shell.

For more info, `man zip` in your shell to bring up the manual or [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) link.